# Integration of Salesforce with Link2Feed. How to convert a Javascript pre-request script into Apex?

Tags: apex, javascript, rest-api

I'm trying an integration of Salesforce with Link2Feed system. I have a pre-request script in postman but it's written in Javascript and I am having trouble converting that code into Apex. I'm not good with coding so I'm looking for guidance, threads, or any material which will help me resolve this problem. Any advice is also appreciated.

The Code is pasted below:

```
var SECRET_KEY = pm.variables.get("SECRET");
var SIGNED_HEADERS = [
    ["host", pm.variables.get("API_URL")]
];
var SIGNED_HEADER = "signed-headers: host,signed-headers\r\n";

function getPath(url) {
    var pathRegex = /.+?\:\/\/.+?(\/.+?)(?:#|\?|$)/;
    var result = url.match(pathRegex);
    return result && result.length > 1 ? result[1] : ''; 
}
 
function getQueryString(url) {
    var arrSplit = url.split('?');
    
    if(arrSplit.length == 1) return '';
    
    var params = arrSplit[1].split('&');
    params.sort();
    
    return '?'+params.join('&');
}
 
function getAuthHeader(httpMethod, requestUrl, requestBody, requestHeaders) {
    if (httpMethod == 'GET' || !requestBody) {
        requestBody = "";
    } else {
        if(requestHeaders != null && requestHeaders["content-type"] != "application/json")
        {
            var output = "";
            Object.keys(requestBody).forEach(function(e) {
                output += escape(e) + "=" + escape(requestBody[e]) + "&";
            });
            requestBody = output.substring(0, output.length -1);
            requestBody = requestBody.replace(/\*/g, '%2A');
        }
    }
    
    console.log(requestBody);
    
    var requestLine = httpMethod +" "+getPath(requestUrl)+getQueryString(requestUrl)+" HTTP/1.1";
    
    var headers = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < SIGNED_HEADERS.length; ++i) {
        headers += (SIGNED_HEADERS[i][0] + ': ' + SIGNED_HEADERS[i][1] + '\r\n');
    }
    headers += SIGNED_HEADER;
    
    //var headers = "host: intake.link2feed.devo\r\nsigned-headers: host,signed-headers\r\n";
    var body = requestBody;
    
    var hashedRequestData = [requestLine, headers, body].join('\r\n');
    console.log(hashedRequestData);
    var hmacDigest = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(hashedRequestData, SECRET_KEY));
    var authHeader = "HMAC-SHA256 "+hmacDigest;
    return authHeader;
}

pm.environment.set("HMAC_AUTH_HEADER", getAuthHeader(request['method'], request['url'], request['data'], request['headers']));
```

Comment: This Signed Headers logic looks very similar to how it works in AWS. You can see a sample implementation I wrote for that [here](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f). It includes sorting the query parameters alphabetically, getting the hash signature, and so on. This isn't going to be a drop-in replacement, though, but it should get you started.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you so much for the edit and the comment. I'll try and get started on this.

Comment: You're welcome! If you haven't yet, you might want to read about [ask] and take the [tour] so you can learn more about what we do here. We don't generally just "write code" (including porting), we encourage people to ask questions when they get stuck. If you have specific questions about an Apex port, and you've made an honest attempt, we'll help keep moving you forward. Use the `{}` to format your code, and remember to include enough detail for us to help you (this question was pretty good, actually). Let us know if you get stuck.